# Mongoid: search an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is it currently possible to search an array of BSON::OrderedHashes with Mongoid based objects? One of my attributes, let's call it `foo` in the `bar` class, looks something like the following:

```
[#<BSON::OrderedHash:0x7f0 {"id"=>"4bf58dd8d48988d118951735", "name"=>"Grocery or Supermarket", "pluralName"=>"Grocery or Supermarkets", "shortName"=>"Grocery Store", "icon"=>#<BSON::OrderedHash:0x7f2 {"prefix"=>"https://foursquare.com/img/categories/shops/food_grocery_", "sizes"=>[32, 44, 64, 88, 256], "name"=>".png"}>, "primary"=>true}>]
```

I want to go through all of my objects and find every one that contains *Grocery* in this order hash for the 'name' attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
Bar.where('foo.name' => /Grocery/)
```

MongoDB's [multikeys support](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) will take care of searching through the array's elements and `'foo.name'` will look for `name` within `foo`.

Comment: @randombits: As an aside, if you can anchor your regex at the beginning (`/^Grocery/` for example) then you could index `foo.name` and MongoDB would use the index for the regex search.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but I think something like this would probably work.

```
Bar.all.select {|b| b.foo.select{|f| f['name'] == 'Grocery'}.size > 0}
```